# Split sentence into phrases and words

Tags: computational-linguistics, multiword-expression

I need a direction, advice where to search information.

I want to split sentences into separate words and phrases.
For example this sentence "Tommy has a lot of job experience" has the phrase "a lot of", and it should be extracted as a phrase, not as separate words "a", "lot", "of".

What tool/library/algorithm/technique can do such extraction or split? 
I am complete newbie, and want to know where to dig.

UPDATE: I plan to do a language learning app, and to give a correct translation for a part of sentence I need to clear distinguish single word from a phrase, because translation will be different. May be this will give some hints.

Comment: It's called "parsing".  I doubt you are right about "a lot of" being a phrase.

Comment: Why not? If split it to separate words - it will lose its meaning, no?

Comment: The chunk _a lot of_ is part of a structure, but it's become frozen because it appears so often. In fact the parsing of _a lot of potatoes_ is often [a lot [of potatoes]] instead of (or in addition to) [[a lot of] potatoes]. Parsers can be set to produce alternative parses in such cases.

Comment: So parser can split sentense into meaningful chunks? Could you name some tools or libraries? And how does he know what chunks to extract? Why it will take "a lot" instead of "a" , "lot"?

Comment: I think for the sake of this question it's unnecessary to get into a syntax-theoretic discussion of how or how not *a lot of* would be a phrase; OP simply wants a tool to solve that problem for him.

Comment: @pro100sanya In the title and in your second sentence you say that you want to "split sentences into separate words and phrases", and then in your example you write "it should be extracted as a phrase, *not* as separate words". What do you want - a tool splitting a sentence into phrases and words or only into phrases and not into words?

Comment: It is true. I need a tool, and some direction to get more info about such kind of problems.

Comment: Have you seen my last comment? It is still not entirely clear to me what you want.

Comment: I have added update. May be it will clarify a bit what i want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52759/discussion-between-pro100sanya-and-lemontree).

Comment: *a lot of* in your example is called a "multiword expression" (MWE). Searching for this term, you will find techniques to identify and extract such beasts. The most simple method is to provide a fixed list of MWEs to your application.

Comment: This is interesting.  Can you edit your question to have more examples of sentences and their ideally split phrases?

Comment: Idk, may be some kind of such things: "has been", "you are".
Thanks for MWE reference, will check that.

Comment: "A lot of" is not a constituent. The constituents are "a lot" + "of job experience" (NP + PP).

Comment: Okay, question could be rephrased like how to find a constituents in the sentence with help of NLP tools or libraries.

Comment: In any case, thank you all for you valuable inputs. Topic can be closed, thanks.